# dragging and dropping in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am new to web development, I am coding some ASP.NET,

I watched many videos about using LINQ to SQL, I am  happy I learned something,

but is it the good way of using is: dragging and dropping and that's done???

what are the best practices to use LINQ to access Database ( my database is not only SQL server..MYSQL..)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to Sql (unfortunately) is designed to only connect with SQL Server. If you have other database types, you may want to give Linq to Entities a go. There are several videos/blogs on the topic.

Depending upon the needs of your application, an understanding of underlying ADO.NET can't hurt either.

As to your original question (dragging and dropping), how good that is will be determined by how good the data design is. For well designed Relational Database Management Systems, I don't see the harm of using a drag'n'drop CRUD/ORM code generation tool like Linq to SQL/Linq to Entities. It handles the mundane tasks of data access and persistence, freeing you to focus on details like the business logic of the application.